# Is it possible to take a snapshot of combined views including the camera?

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, snapshot

My app has a button that should take a screenshot of whatever is on the screen by calling "takeSnapShot" (see code below).
I have two views and one of them is a picker view that I use for the camera, so in the screen I see the image coming from the camera and next to it another view with images.

The thing is that I capture the screen but it doesn't capture the image coming from the camera.

Also, I think I render the view.layer but the debugger keeps saying>

> "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates."

Any ideas? Thanks!

This is the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

UIImage *capturaPantalla;


-(void)takeSnapShot:(id)sender{

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(picker.view.window.bounds.size);
   [picker.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   capturaPantalla = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturaPantalla,nil,nil,nil);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the similar function before, and used AVCaptureSession to make it.

```
 // 1. Create the AVCaptureSession
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self setSession:session];

 // 2. Setup the preview view
    [[self previewView] setSession:session];

 // 3. Check for device authorization
    [self checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus];

    dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [self setSessionQueue:sessionQueue];
```

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
My countdown snapshot function:

```
- (void) takePhoto
{
    [timer1 invalidate];
    dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
        // 4. Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.
        [[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];

        // 5. Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
        [iSKITACamViewController setFlashMode:flashMode forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];

        AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = [[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        CGFloat maxScale = stillImageConnection.videoMaxScaleAndCropFactor;
        if (effectiveScale > 1.0f && effectiveScale < maxScale)
        {
            stillImageConnection.videoScaleAndCropFactor = effectiveScale;;
        }

        [self playSound];
        // 6.Capture a still image.
        [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

            if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
            {
                NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                if(iPhone5 && [self.modeLabel.text isEqualToString:@"PhotoMode"]) {
                    UIImage *image1 = [image crop:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
                    [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image1 CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image1 imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
                } else {
                    [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];

                }
                self.priveImageView.image = image;
            }
        }];
    });
}
```

Comment: That could be a nicer approach, although the snapshot should contain the camera preview and an image in front. i.e. : a self portrait with an image of a hat. That's driving me crazy!

Comment: Also tried [this option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248035/how-to-capture-photo-by-adding-overlay) but still getting the same results.

Comment: I put some of my classes on my github for your reference. Hope it helpful.
https://github.com/htaiwan/CameraSnapShot.git